# how to match sentence with excluding words in php

Tags: php, arrays

i need to match a sentence to an array key excluding some words, such as "How can I add **new booking"** I want to search for only new booking excluding what is before it. Knowing that the words before it might be different such as how may i add **new booking**

and here is what I have done so far

```
$array = [ "booking" => "Here you can etc..", "new booking|new hotel booking|booking|how to add new booking" => "here you can"]

  $query = "how can i add new booking";

  $pattern = '/' . $query . "/i"; 
  $matches  = preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($array));
  if ($matches) {
                $msg = $array[head($matches)];
  } else {
                $msg = __('basic.bot no answer');
  }
```

`$query = "how can i add new booking";`
it returns nothing, but if the query is `new booking` works fine

Comment: Can a simple `str_contains` with a loop be used? You'd just need to handle deciding what to do when more than one thing matches. https://3v4l.org/PGNYM#v8.2.7

Comment: I have tried it and it works fine but when I am using the value like that in the key "new booking|new hotel booking|booking|how to add new booking" return nothing, so how to exclude |

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question. Your code doesn't help either. That said, I have a feeling that a fuzzy full-text search is what you're looking for. I'd look into e.g. Elasticsearch for that instead of trying to implement something myself.

Comment: If you want to use `|` as a delimiter in your strings, that also is what RegEx uses for "or". As long as your keys don't contain any additional things that might trip up RegEx you can probably just use `preg_match` with a loop instead: https://3v4l.org/ictKp#v8.2.7

Comment: i just need to match a sentence if the input has any words that can be matched in the array for example if I write "I need to add new book" can be match to the key array of "new book"

Comment: Question is unclear but maybe https://3v4l.org/Fi9fa helps?? What are you excluding?

Comment: If you really want to match on _any_ word in the provided input, against _any_ word in the lookup array, I think this is what you are looking for: https://3v4l.org/LuQeN#v8.2.7. The definition of "word" might need some cleanup, too, possibly removing punctuation.